# Flexbox center vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to have a horizontally and vertically centered content on one of my webpage. I've done it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Eko</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>    
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>    
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div class="login-container">    
      <h1>Hello</h1>    
    </div>    
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </body>    
</html>
```

And this is my CSS.

```
.login-container {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}
```

However, the vertical center doesn't occur (just the horizontal). 
It works when I apply this CSS.

```
body {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}
```

Why does it only work when we have it applied to body?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19026884/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your container has no height settings, so it only uses as much vertical space as needed by its contents, therefore there will be no vertical centering. If you apply `height: 100%` to it (and also to `body` to have a reference height), it should work as desired.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can I assume that `<body>` has a default height of 100%?

Answer (score 2):

In addition you must give to **both** your html & body tags an height, for instance :

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

So, your container is also vertically centered.